# What are slots used for?

Tags: validator, slots

I try to understand what slots are for. ethereum has same term but everything I read about slots are so abstract. From different solana docs, I read those

> Solana has 432,000 slots per epoch which amounts to ~2 days. Each
> epoch has a randomly generated predefined leader schedule that defines
> which validator is expected to produce a block per slot. A slot can
> then either contain a block or not (skipped slot).
>
> A slot refers to the period of time in which a slot leader produces
> ledger entries. The minimum slot time is 400ms. We display the time it
> took the current leader to ingest transactions and produce a block.
>
> The period of time for which each leader ingests transactions and
> produces a block. Collectively, slots create a logical clock. Slots
> are ordered sequentially and non-overlapping, comprising roughly equal
> real-world time as per PoH.

All those are so abstract. can someone explain what it is used for? What is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slots and Epoch are simply units of time on Solana. A slot is the smallest unit, and 432000 of it makes an Epoch.

> A slot can then either contain a block or not (skipped slot).
> A slot refers to the period of time in which a slot leader produces ledger entries.
> The period of time for which each leader ingests transactions and produces a block.

There's the concept of a `leader` in Solana. A `leader` for a particular period is the only validator that is allowed to produce a block.

Solana has a system that changes the leader frequently. The window of opportunity a leader has to produce a block before that privilege is re-assigned to a different validator is called a `slot`.